How using samba-tool I can cleanly re-add a pc to DC
From:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/406010/dc-cannot-ping-its-client-computer-by-hostname-but
I found to delete a computer from a DC and add it again I need to follow:

Delete the computer in the Domain controller and make sure no record was left behind in the DNS forward lookup zone.
Disjoin the client to the domain, restart the client
Join the client to DC again.
Check the DNS setting in the DC: If virtualization is used, under the the virtual NIC (created by Hyper-V) where applicable to your DC/AD, one of the DNS server will have to be the DC itself (either IP address or loopback address 127.0.0.1) so that it will resolve the internal computer hostnames. The other DNS could point to other DNS server (to PiHole server in our case). So,

DNS 1: the DC
DNS 2: Pi-hole server
How can do all these steps with Samba Server? I have a problem with a computer X (Ubuntu server 24.04LTS) that I was adding and changing its ip addresses (ex: my windows machine can not find that X pc) while being in my Samba based AD controller.

The "samba-tool" Command is typically for performing DNS/Domain related functions, on a Linux/Samba Domain Controller. It wasn't really built to perform functions, in relation to Domain Clients, etc.
If you simply want to Remove a Computer from your Domain, using "samba-tool", you can use the following Command.
samba-tool computer delete <computername> [options]

To Re-Add the Computer to your Domain, you can use the following Command.
samba-tool computer create computername [Options]

For a list of available Options, you may want to review the following "samba-tool" Documentation.
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/4.9/man-html/samba-tool.8.html#computer%20create%20computername%20%5Boptions%5D
The task of Re-Joining your Computer to the Domain typically needs to be completed on the Windows Client, itself (just as you would, in an All Window Environment). You can find additional information by following the link below.
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Joining_a_Windows_Client_or_Server_to_a_Domain
In fact, the following two Samba Wikis are filled with useful info.
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Main_Page
https://wiki.indie-it.com/wiki/Samba
If you would like to perform the Un-Join/Re-Join tasks Remotely, you may want to check out the "Remove-Computer" & "Add-Computer" PowerShell Cmdlets. Of course, you are going to need to have a WinRM & Remote PowerShell Setup/Configured in your Domain Environment, to run Remote PowerShell Commands.
I'll do some more digging, when I have time and if I come across anything that may also benefit you, I'll be sure to stop back and post a comment.
I hope this helps to point you in the right direction.
